# Call a method of all parallel Class Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, methods, synchronized

I have a question for you.
I have multiple Threads runnings of a class called ServerThread. When an specific event happens on ANY of those threads, I want to call a method of every other thread running in parallel.

```
public class ServerThread implements Runnable {

private TCPsocket clientSocket;

public ServerThread(Socket comSocket){
    clientSocket = new TCPsocket(comSocket);
}

@Override
public void run(){
    boolean waiting = true;
    Message msg;
    try{
        while(waiting){
            msg = clientSocket.getMessage();
            shareMessage(msg);

        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        ErrorLogger.toFile("EndConnection", e.toString());
    }
}

public void shareMessage(Message msg){
        clientSocket.sendMessage(msg);
}

}
```

I am talking about this specific line

**shareMessage(msg);**

which I would like to be called on every thread/instance

-- so that a message is sent to every client (in all tcp connections)

I've tried with synchronized but either I'm not using it well or that is not what I am looking for.

Another thing that might work is keeping a class with an static member which is a list of those tcpconnection objects and then do some loop in all every time.

Thanks for your help and time.

---

Edited with one possible solution

*Add an static array as a member of the class and add/remove objects of same class (or tcp sockets would also work)

```
private static ArrayList<ServerThread> handler;
...
handler.add(this);
...
handler.remove(this); //when client exists and thread stops
```

*Then create a method that iterates for each connection, and make it synchronized so that two threads won't interact at the same time. You may want to implement synchronized on your message sending methods as well.

```
public void shareMessage(Message msg){
        //this.clientSocket.sendMessage(msg);
        synchronized (handler){
            for(ServerThread connection: handler){
                try{
                    connection.clientSocket.sendMessage(msg);
                } catch(Exception e){
                    connection.clientSocket.closeConnection();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: `synchronized` is required to prevent race conditions when multiple threads want to call the same method and this method accesses/modifies shared data. So maybe (probably) you will need it somewhere but it does not provide you the functionality you require.

Second: You cannot command an other thread to call a method directly. It is not possible e.g. for `ThreadA` to call `methodX` in `ThreadB`.

I guess you have one thread per client. Probably each thread will block at `clientSocket.getMessage()` until the client sends a message. I don't know the implementation of `TCPsocket` but maybe it is possible to [interrupt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt--) the thread. In this case you may need to catch a [`InterruptedException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/InterruptedException.html) and ask some central data structure if the interrupt was caused because of a new shared message and to return the shared message.

Maybe it is also possible for `TCPsocket.getMessage()` to return, if no message was received for some time, in which case you would again have to ask a central data structure if there is a new shared message.

Maybe it is also possible to store all client connections in such a data structure and loop them every time, as you suggested. But keep in mind that the client might send a message at any time, maybe even at the exact same time when you try to send it the shared message received from another client. This might be no problem but this depends on your application. Also you have to consider that the message will also be shared with the client that sent it to your server in the first place…

Also take a look at [`java.util.concurrent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) and its subpackages, it is likely you find something useful there… ;-)

---

To summarize: There are many possibilities. Which one is the best depends on what you need. Please add some more detail to your question if you need more specific help.

Comment: I got it to work doing that about looping some objects. Anyway, thank you for your response since it helped me getting things more clear about other possibilities and about what I could not do.
I will update op with solution so other people can check it out